# Unable to send email using graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

The below code is used to retrieve token

```cs
IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                        .Create(clientId)
                        .WithTenantId(tenantId)
                        .WithClientSecret(clientsec)
                       
                        .Build();

                AuthorizationCodeProvider authprovider = new AuthorizationCodeProvider(confidentialClientApplication, scopes);
                //ClientCredentialProvider authprovider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);
                var authResult = await confidentialClientApplication
                        .AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
                        .ExecuteAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                return authResult.AccessToken;
```

and calling sending mail using Me is not working.

```cs
                        await graphServiceClient.Me
                            .SendMail(email, false)
                             .Request()
                             .PostAsync();
```

Can someone assist what is the wrong here?

In my scenario I have to send mails to using multiple from addresses.

Comment: Are you trying to send emails using "multiple FROM(sent onbehalf of)" email addresses?

Comment: Also i see that you're using Me endpoint and trying to send email FROM multiple email addresses. Me is not meant for it. I would suggest you to check the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the ClientCredentials (that means there is no user) so `.Me()` isn’t available.

To send a mail as a specific user, you’ll need to reference the user.
Here is a sample How that works for teams. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/create-requests?tabs=CS#updating-an-existing-entity-with-patch

```cs
var userId = "71766077-aacc-470a-be5e-ba47db3b2e88";

await graphClient.Users[userId]
  .SendMail(email, false)
  .Request()
  .PostAsync();
```

I’m not sure if you can also use the username (upn) instead of the id.